# Передача экземпляра класса либо экземпляра наследника этого класса в качестве аргумента

Tags: typescript

В приведённом ниже коде класс `ExampleClass` имеет один обязательный аргумент - экземпляр класса `DependencyBase` либо его наследника, однако во время разработки классов `ExampleClass` и `DependencyBase` заранее неизвестно, какое имя будет иметь класс-наследник.

```
class ExampleClass {
    constructor(dependency: DependencyBase) {
        // code...
    }
}

class DependencyBase {
    // ...
}

class Dependency extends DependencyBase {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

let dependency = new Dependency();
let foo = new ExampleClass(dependency);
```

Этот код работать не будет, потому что в `let foo = new ExampleClass(dependency);` параметр `dependency` является экземпляром класса `Dependency`, а требуется - экземпляр `DependencyBase`. Поскольку во время разработки класса `ExampleClass` мы заранее не знаем, какое имя будет иметь класс-наследник, по прописать `constructor(dependency: DependencyBase | Dependency)` мы не можем.

Как же быть?

Comment: Не особо знаю typescript, но что то подсказывает копать в сторону интерфейса и DI

Comment: @dev_null, к сожалению, в TypeScript [так просто не получится](https://nehalist.io/dependency-injection-in-typescript/#interfacesaregoneaftercompilation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let foo = new ExampleClass(dependency as DependencyBase);
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Попробовал. Если мы добавим какие-либо новые свойства в классе `Dependency` (что вполне естественно при наследовании классов), будет ошибка `TS2322: Type 'DependencyBase' is not assignable to type 'Dependency'. Property 'newClassField is missing in type 'DependencyBase'. `

Comment: @БоковГлеб мне затруднительно представить, как этот код может вызывать эту ошибку, - преобразование идет в другую сторону, от наследника к родителю, это должно быть возможно всегда

Comment: Bозможно Вы правы. Думаю, причина ошибки кроется где-то ещё. Буду выяснять.

Comment: Понял, в чём дело. Я попытался вызвать свойство наследника (`Dependency`) внутри `ExampleClass`. Понятно, что TypeScript такого свойства не ожидает. Вы же ответили правильно! Ещё раз спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @БоковГлеб Пожалуйста. Рад был помочь.